# Template Matching: efficient way to create mask for minMaxLoc?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

Template matching in OpenCV is great. And you can pass a mask to cv2.minMaxLoc so that you only search (sort of) in part of the image for the template you want. You can also use a mask at the matchTemplate operation, but this only masks the template.

I want to find a template and I want to be assured that this template is within some other region of my image.

Calculating the mask for minMaxLoc seems kind of heavy. That is, calculating an ***accurate*** mask feels heavy. If you calculate a mask the easy way, it ignores the size of the template.

Examples are in order. My input images are show below. They're a bit contrived. I want to find the candy bar, but only if it's ***completely*** inside the white circle of the clock face.

clock1
[image: clock1]

clock2
[image: clock2]

template
[image: template]

In clock1, the candy bar is inside the circular clock face and it's a "PASS". But in clock2, the candy bar is only partially inside the face and I want it to be a "FAIL". Here's a code sample for doing it the easy way. I use cv.HoughCircles to find the clock face.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('clock1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('template.png')
t_h, t_w = template.shape[0:2]  # template height and width

# find circle in gray image using Hough transform
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, method = cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, 
                           minDist  = 150, param1 = 50, param2 = 70,
                           minRadius = 131, maxRadius = 200)
i = circles[0,0]
x0 = i[0]
y0 = i[1]
r  = i[2] 

# display circle on color image
cv2.circle(img,(x0, y0), r,(0,255,0),2)

# do the template match
result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

# finally, here is the part that gets tricky. we want to find highest
# rated match inside circle and we'd like to use minMaxLoc

# make mask by drawing circle on zero array
mask = np.zeros(result.shape, dtype = np.uint8)  # minMaxLoc will throw
                                                 # error w/o np.uint8
cv2.circle(mask, (x0, y0), r, color = 1, thickness = -1)

# call minMaxLoc
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result, mask = mask)

# draw found rectangle on img
if max_val > 0.4:  # use 0.4 as threshold for finding candy bar
    cv2.rectangle(img, max_loc, (max_loc[0]+t_w, max_loc[1]+t_h), (0,255,0), 4)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img)
```

output using clock1
[image: output from clock1]

output using clock2
finds candy bar even
though part of it is outside circle
[image: output from clock2]

So to properly make a mask, I use a bunch of NumPy operations. I make four separate masks (one for each corner of the template bounding box) and then AND them together. I'm not aware of any convenience functions in OpenCV that would do the mask for me. I'm a little nervous that all of the array operations will be expensive. Is there a better way to do this?

```
h, w = result.shape[0:2]

# make arrays that hold x,y coords 
grid = np.indices((h, w))
x = grid[1]
y = grid[0]

top_left_mask  = np.hypot(x - x0, y - y0) - r < 0
top_right_mask = np.hypot(x + t_w - x0, y - y0) - r < 0
bot_left_mask  = np.hypot(x - x0, y + t_h - y0) - r < 0
bot_right_mask = np.hypot(x + t_w - x0, y + t_h - y0) - r < 0

mask = np.logical_and.reduce((top_left_mask, top_right_mask, 
                              bot_left_mask, bot_right_mask))
mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask*255)
```

Here's what the "fancy" mask looks like:
[image]

Seems about right. It cannot be circular because of the template shape. If I run clock2.jpg with this mask I get:
[image: output with fancy mask on clock2.jpg]

It works. No candy bars are identified. But I wish I could do it in fewer lines of code...

**EDIT**:
I've done some profiling. I ran 100 cycles of the "easy" way and the "accurate" way and calculated frames per second (fps):

- easy way:     12.7 fps
- accurate way:  7.8 fps

so there is some price to pay for making the mask with NumPy. These tests were done on a relatively powerful workstation. It could get uglier on more modest hardware...

Comment: Is the speed actually a problem for you? Bitwise operations on arrays are not particularly expensive---linear in the size of the array, like most things. Stuff like this can easily run real-time in 30fps for typical (e.g. not extravagantly large HDF-5 type) images. By far the largest hit to your speed is the template matching itself, which is O(n*m) where n is the image size and m is the template size. The masking ops are only O(n), as is the `minMaxLoc()`. Since the image size is reduced greatly by masking, you're cutting out the largest piece of the puzzle already.

Comment: Oh wait---your code isn't using the `mask` parameter for the template matching step. Do you have any particular aversion to using normalized cross-correlation or square difference for template matching instead of the correlation coefficient? If you use one of those methods, you can pass in a `mask` parameter to `matchTemplate()`, which will be a better speed up than the rest of this. It simply will only look for matches within the mask. More [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html).

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds: I've found both TM_SQDIFF and TM_CCORR_NORMED to not work well for my application -- I don't get sufficient discrimination to weed out false matches. But you gave me another idea: maybe it would be cheaper to pass a  pre-masked image to cv2.matchTemplate. The NumPy way would be to create a mask and do np.multiply (element-wise multiplication) with original image.

Comment: That won't help. It will still go through the whole image. Just because the elements are black/zero doesn't mean "don't match this"---of course, you may be trying to find a patch of black! I still think my first question is important though---is this something you've profiled and figured out is actually slow? Because numpy array operations are extremely quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1: 'mask' image before cv2.matchTemplate

Just for kicks, I tried to make my own mask of the image that I pass to [cv2.matchTemplate](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html) to see what kind of performance I can achieve. To be clear, this isn't a proper mask -- I set all of the pixels to ignore to one color (black or white). This is to get around the fact only TM_SQDIFF and TM_CORR_NORMED support a proper mask.

@Alexander Reynolds makes a very good point in the comments that some care must be taken if the template image (the thing we're trying to find) has lots of black or lots of white. For many problems, we will know *a priori* what the template looks like and we can specify a white background or black background.

I use [cv2.multiply](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.htm), which seems to be faster than [numpy.multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html). `cv2.multiply` has the added advantage that it automatically clips the results to the range 0 to 255.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

img = cv2.imread('clock1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('target.jpg')
t_h, t_w = template.shape[0:2]  # template height and width

mask_background = 'WHITE'

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(100):  # do 100 cycles for timing
    # find circle in gray image using Hough transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, method = cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, 
                               minDist  = 150, param1 = 50, param2 = 70,
                               minRadius = 131, maxRadius = 200)
    i = circles[0,0]
    x0 = i[0]
    y0 = i[1]
    r  = i[2] 

    # display circle on color image
    cv2.circle(img,(x0, y0), r,(0,255,0),2)

    if mask_background == 'BLACK':  # black = 0, white = 255 on grayscale
        mask = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype = np.uint8)

    elif mask_background == 'WHITE':
        mask = 255*np.ones(img.shape, dtype = np.uint8)

    cv2.circle(mask, (x0, y0), r, color = (1,1,1), thickness = -1)
    img2 = cv2.multiply(img, mask)  # element wise multiplication
                                    # values > 255 are truncated at 255
    # do the template match
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img2, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    # call minMaxLoc
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    # draw found rectangle on img
    if max_val > 0.4:
        cv2.rectangle(img, max_loc, (max_loc[0]+t_w, max_loc[1]+t_h), (0,255,0), 4)

fps = 100/(time.time()-start_time)
print('fps ', fps)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img)
```

Profiling results:

- BLACK background 12.3 fps
- WHITE background 12.1 fps

Using this method has very little performance hit relative to 12.7 fps in original question. However, it has the drawback that it will still find templates that still stick over the edge a little bit. Depending on the exact nature of the problem, this may be acceptable in many applications.

## Method 2: use [cv2.boxFilter](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html) to create mask for minMaxLoc

In this technique, we start with a circular mask (as in OP), but then modify it with cv2.boxFilter. We change the `anchor` from default center of kernel to the top left corner (0, 0)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

img = cv2.imread('clock1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('target.jpg')
t_h, t_w = template.shape[0:2]  # template height and width
print('t_h, t_w ', t_h, ' ', t_w)

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(100):
    # find circle in gray image using Hough transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, method = cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, 
                               minDist  = 150, param1 = 50, param2 = 70,
                               minRadius = 131, maxRadius = 200)
    i = circles[0,0]
    x0 = i[0]
    y0 = i[1]
    r  = i[2] 

    # display circle on color image
    cv2.circle(img,(x0, y0), r,(0,255,0),2)

    # do the template match
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    # finally, here is the part that gets tricky. we want to find highest
    # rated match inside circle and we'd like to use minMaxLoc

    # start to make mask by drawing circle on zero array
    mask = np.zeros(result.shape, dtype = np.float)  
    cv2.circle(mask, (x0, y0), r, color = 1, thickness = -1)

    mask = cv2.boxFilter(mask, 
                         ddepth = -1, 
                         ksize = (t_w, t_h), 
                         anchor = (0,0),
                         normalize = True,
                         borderType = cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED)
    # mask now contains values from zero to 1. we want to make anything
    # less than 1 equal to zero
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, thresh = 0.9999, 
                        maxval = 1.0, type = cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)

    # call minMaxLoc
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result, mask = mask)

    # draw found rectangle on img
    if max_val > 0.4:
        cv2.rectangle(img, max_loc, (max_loc[0]+t_w, max_loc[1]+t_h), (0,255,0), 4)

fps = 100/(time.time()-start_time)
print('fps ', fps)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img)
```

This code gives a mask identical to OP, but at 11.89 fps. This technique gives us more accuracy with slightly more performance hit than **Method 1**.